# Swedish "personnummer" (personal identity number) in SQL

Tags: sql, database, normalization

This is a specific instance of an old problem: How to store "numbers" (e.g. phone numbers, IP addresses, social security numbers) in SQL databases?

Background: In Sweden, Personal Identity Numbers ("personnummer") are extremely common: You use them when communicating with the government, the bank, your employer, etc. People born in Sweden are assigned them when born. My immigrant friends lament the dark couple of weeks before they got a personnummer and could finally get a debit card and start looking for jobs.

My organization needs to store personnummer of our members. We have a SQL database for this. **How should I store the data?**

---

From Wikipedia, regarding the format of a [personnummer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Personal_identity_number_%28Sweden%29):

> The personal identity number consists of 10 digits and a hyphen. The first six correspond to the person's birthday, in YYMMDD form. They are followed by a hyphen. People over the age of 100 replace the hyphen with a plus sign. The seventh through ninth are a serial number. An odd ninth number is assigned to males and an even ninth number is assigned to females. Some county authorities, such as Stockholm, and some banks, have started using 12 digit numbers to allow YYYYMMDD. This format is also used on some Swedish ID-cards[clarification needed] and on the Swedish European Health Insurance Cards but not on state-issued identity documents.
>
> The tenth digit is a checksum which was introduced in 1967 when the system was computerized.

So, a personnummer could be "120101-3842" for a person born this year. This is also commonly formatted as "20120101-3842" because of Y2K and "replacing the hyphen with a plus sign" is not well-known.

In a database column, I imagine I can:

- Store it as a `VARCHAR`, formatted as "120101-3842", "20120101-3842" or "201201013842" (shaving of a byte by getting of the superfluous hyphen in the YYYYMMDD-format).
- Store the full `YYYYMMDDXXXX` as an `INTEGER`, which is too big for 32 bits but fits without problems in 64 bits.

There won't be any issues with leading zeroes in this case, and using a VARCHAR is almost twice the size. Unlike IP addresses, storing this number as an INTEGER does not make it harder to read for a human (i.e. "127.0.0.1" compared to `2130706433`).

I appreciate the "strictness" of an `INTEGER` column but also feel that this might run into unseen issues.

EDIT: We have a real need to validate this input with the checksum et cetera, which requires doing math on the indivdual digits (multiplying, summing etc). Since digits aren't really ... uh... part of a quantity, but of decimal formatting, it might make sense to consider it a varchar after all.

Comment: Store it as a varchar and create a check constraint (e.g. using a regex) to validate the content (only numeric, 10 character minimum etc)

Comment: how to validate it in javascript?

Comment: @YatinMistry I think that question is somewhat off-topic. Validation of personummer is done with a simple [Luhn algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luhn_algorithm). By Googling, I found an [implementation using jQuery](https://github.com/wallin/jquery-validate-personnummer), but it's trivial to build your own.

Answer (score 1):

Use `VARCHAR` with a fixed length because it is the most simple approach. And I don't think that your organisation will store the number of all 9.5 million inhabitants so that saving space is a real design goal? :)

Comment: No, that's true which is why I feel a bit silly... We only have about 3000 members so the savings are around 300 KB, which isn't really something to care about.

Comment: I prefer the simple way, mainly because of maintainabiliy and the reason that others also have to read and understand the code. Unless you really depend on speed/space/..., then simple is usually the opposite of fast/small/...

Answer (score 1):

So, as I understand it, the hyphen / plus signs are only required for the format with 2 digit year.

If I were you, I would on the application side convert to the 4 digit year format (And drop the hyphen). Then store the resulting value as an integer. As you have stated, this will save space, and will allow you to mathematically transform the values (Although I imagine that on personal numbers this may be irrelevant).

I think the key here is that you should choose a **single format** rather than trying to manage two different formats in the database. This will also help to lead to application consistency. When it comes to external applications that require one or another format, you can place a transform into the transfer code.

On a side note, it should be fairly trivial to create a trigger that would automatically assign the 2 digit year format (As long as you replace the hyphen / plus with a digit) To the 4 year format.

Comment: Right the hyphen is just a formatting thing with 12 digits. Regarding math: We want to implement the checksum algorithm to validate the numbers (similar to Luhn but not the same). I don't think it's easier to work with individual digits in a number than string though...

Comment: Yeah... If you need to do a checksum, then varchar may be easier to work with. I think my point on the single format issue still stands though :) And if you do choose a format you can set it to char(length) as opposed to varchar (which should help with the space issues)

Answer (score 1):

I would store the canonical form 201201013842 as a CHAR (rather than a VARCHAR).

The bottom line is that you do not control the semantics of the number (Swedish authorities do). If at some point they decide to add non numeric characters to the number (as the number already does in the older format), you will be better equipped to deal with the change.

Comment: This is a very good point. However, since "120101-3842" is the "official" form (to extent one exists), I'd say your canonical argument is in favor of that one. What if the authorities decide to replace the hyphen with a slash to designate something? It's currently meaningless if you use the long, unofficial form but, as you imply, who knows what the future brings..

Comment: The choice of what you will use as canonical form has less impact.What is important is that all numbers are stored in the same way. My preference was motivated by two things : the YYYYMMDD... format seems to become the new standard, and the logic to extract the birth date from it is simpler.

Answer (score 1):

We have the same problem and we currently store it as `yyyyMMdd-xxxx`, but if i where to redesign this today i would store the `yyyyMMdd` in a `date` field as that would handle the validation of the date, then i would store the 4 other values in a nchar(4) and add a constraint to ensure its only numbers.

Comment: why bother validating the date when the tenth character is already a [checksum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Personal_identity_number_%28Sweden%29#Checksum) for all the other numbers? why wouldn't you use that for validating?

Comment: @eis The checksum can be correct while the date isen't, that dosen't mean its a valid personnummer.